# Round window on Wolfholm

Tags: part-identification

There is a round window in the [Wolfholm build](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legols/50165797643/in/photostream) by Jonas Kramm.  It's on the left side, top floor. Can anyone identify the round white piece and the smaller round black piece inside. (might be a pulley).

Comment: The insert is a Black Wedge Wheel (Pulley wheel).

Answer (score 8):

The obvious part is [Technic, Wedge Belt Wheel (Pulley)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4185) as Phil mentioned in the comments.

[image]

Other, not so obvious piece is [Brick, Round 4 x 4 with Recessed Center](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=68325), which comes in new [Minions set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75551-1). It only comes in Light Bluish Gray [BL] color at this moment.

[image]

Jonas has confirmed this over his [IG post](https://www.instagram.com/p/CDZFamVoNze/):

> It's a Minion Eye.